# Apex Code to send Email Alert

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

How to write apex code to send email alert for record owner change to the old record owner with the fields information ? Help Pls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm to learn more about  sending outbound emails.

Here's a sample code that sends email to previous owner when the owner is changed:

```
trigger SendEmailOnOwnerChange on Account (after update) {
    if (trigger.old[0].OwnerId != trigger.new[0].OwnerId) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        String emailAddr = [select Email from User where Id = :trigger.old[0].OwnerId].Email;
        String newOwnerName = [select Name from User where Id = :trigger.new[0].OwnerId].Name;

        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {emailAddr};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

        mail.setSubject('Owner Changed for Account : ' + trigger.new[0].Name);

        mail.setPlainTextBody('Owner of Account: ' + trigger.new[0].Name + ' Changed to ' + newOwnerName);
        mail.setHtmlBody('Owner of Account: <b>' + trigger.new[0].Name + '</b> Changed to <b>' + newOwnerName  + '</b>');

        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

Of course it currently works for only one record and needs to be bulkified for bulk update.

Comment: To those visiting this post, PLEASE keep in mind that limits for single emails are typically much less than those for email alerts. You can send to AT MOST 5,000 external recipients using the single email route whereas you can typically send 1,000 email alerts per Salesforce license in your org. This answer is not a replacement for email alerts if the desire is to send a high volume of emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a generic alert for all objects.
Instead, write an after update trigger for the objects that you are interested in that compare the `Trigger.old[n].OwnerId` and `Trigger.new[n].OwnerId`.

I would recommend putting the comparison code in a class method that all your triggers call. You can use [Dynamic Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_dynamic.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_dynamic.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) for this purpose with the `sObject` type.

In the new class method, use the [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_email_outbound.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) class to send the alert.